# Can javascript template engine ignore some tags <w:t></w:t>?

Tags: javascript, templates, ms-word, openxml, docx

I am working on a docx template application.

```
var data={ firstname:"david", age: 12}
var template= " {{firstname}} is {{age}} years old."
```

Normally, using the above data and template will render:

```
david is 12 years old.
```

In my case, the template string will first be written in Microsoft word, and then I will use getOOxml command ( office.js library ), something like this will be returned.

```
var template = "<w:t>{{</w:t><w:t>firstname</w:t><w:t>}}</w:t> is <w:t>{{</w:t><w:t>age</w:t><w:t>}}</w:t> years old."
```

The reason why I use getOOxml rather than getText command is that OOxml can contain format information but Text can not.

I'd like to use javascript template engine for rendering, but the `<w:t>` tag stops template engine from working.

Is there a javascript template engine can ingore `<w:t>`?

Answer (score 0):

Use regex to remove those tags before running through handlebars.js or whatever pre-processor you're using.

```
var source = "<w:t>{{</w:t><w:t>firstname</w:t><w:t>}}</w:t> is <w:t>{{</w:t><w:t>age</w:t><w:t>}}</w:t> years old.";

// Remove those tags.
source = source.replace(/\<w\:t\>/g, "").replace(/\<\/w\:t\>/g, "");

// Run your template through your pre-processor.
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
```

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/Ly48395t/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This may be a good solution, but not what I want. I hope to keep those <w:t> tags (or temporarily remove them and put them back later) as <w:t> tags can contain some other information which is not shown in the above example, and those information are important.

Comment: Then replace them with `<span>` tag with a data attribute or something. `<span data-docx-tag="&lt;w:t&gt;">`. That way you can go back later and parse out what the original tag was while still having valid HTML.